# Page views using curl PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying visit a blog using curl and my understanding about curl is that it would increase the page views. I am using stat counter on the same blog to capture visitor statistics, but I don't see any increase after using the curl script several times. 
`

```
<?php
$site="http://forex-eguide.blogspot.com";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$return=curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
?>
```

`

what am I doing wrong here or am I missing anything or is my understanding incorrect...

I am running the php on my windows xp and apache 2.2.x

Comment: It depends on what methods your stat counter uses to count visits

Comment: I don't see that you even initialized cURL with curl_init anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: See your using stat counter, which fetches a 1x1px image to log the hit. If you was using a stat counter which used cookies then you wouldn't have the same issue.

Comment: its a javascript that i place in my log totrack stats

Comment: You write that you're running php on "your windows xp", so your curl and your browser "might" have the same ip and one ip is counted only once... and JS is not executed by curl requests

Comment: sorry missed out $curl=curl_init(); while copying here

Comment: @straubrry: still in that case i should see the page views increase right??

Comment: As pointed out, you (and us) don't know HOW your counter works. It might be bound to IP address so it increases the visits by 1 only once per IP during certain time frame, it might only increase visits when it recognizes that a browser is requesting the URL and so on. If you're planning to "cheat" on your visit stats - I'd kindly suggest you don't do that :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to pose as a browser by setting the agent.

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13')
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, cURL will only get you the HTML as plain text. So if your tracker for example uses a script, this script would first of all have to be downloaded in addition to the webpage you fetched. Secondly the JavaScript will have to be interpreted and run (like a browser do). Don't think cURL does this. Same if it uses a tiny picture. This picture would have to be downloaded too, but don't think cURL does this automatically. It just grabs the plain HTML.

If the stat tracking happens server side, as part of the request that results in the HTML you get back, then it should work to just "touch" it with cURL.